# How to force a refesh on =importdata()?

Tags: google-sheets

My script previously used to work, however, I noticed recently that when I have this script active with a 5-minute interval trigger, it does not work. However, when I run the script it will load the data but it won't be updated data. It will actually only update the data when I delete the script, and then delete the function and re-paste it.
:

```
function allergen()
{
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('Backend Data!H2').setValue('=importdata("https://app.periscopedata.com/api/company_name/chart/csv/cd30345f-08fe-808a-93cc-7e32a19353f4")')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the answer from [Google sheets importData, importRange speed / interval - ways to improve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069891/google-sheets-importdata-importrange-speed-interval-ways-to-improve-it?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Additionally, you can also check this other method from this post about **[enforcing a refresh to IMPORTDATA function at a certain interval](https://gist.github.com/jaygooby/9932518#gistcomment-2015663)**.