# How to make data auto update in google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I am importing some data using `=importData("URL")`. after filtering my data, **How to make the data auto-update whenever the source gets updated?** Sometimes the data for a country is for 11-5-2021 and another country is 12-5-2021

This is the data source: https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-data.csv

I've just typed this script in AppsScript but it still didn't work and stuck there!

```
    function myFunction() {
  function importData()
  {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var url = 'https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv';
    var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(text);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Cases And Deaths Sheet');
    for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
      sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
  }
  importData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to a recommendation from an answer on a similar post [Google sheets importData, importRange speed / interval - ways to improve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069891/google-sheets-importdata-importrange-speed-interval-ways-to-improve-it?answertab=votes#tab-top), where you can just clear the cell with IMPORTDATA function first then add the IMPORTDATA back in every x minutes in your script function.

Alternatively, you can also check this recommended method from [using importdata function and forcing a refresh at a certain interval](https://gist.github.com/jaygooby/9932518#gistcomment-2015663), where the script contains a time-based trigger to force refresh IMPORTDATA function on your sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Putting this on a time based trigger will update you data automatically
function importData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const url = 'https://covid19.who.int/WHO-COVID-19-global-table-data.csv';
  const text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(text);
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange(1,1,csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
//run this once and it should call importData every day at some giving time between 5 and 6 am
//you can run it more often because it checks to make sure that there isn't already a trigger for that function name
function createTrigger()  {
  const triggers=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().map(t=>t.getHandlerFunction());
  if(!~triggers.indexOf('importData')) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('importData').timeBased().everyDays(1).atHour(5).create();
  }
}
```